# Deserializing null into a specific object in gson

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, rx-java

I have this old implementation of awebservice class, which works off of retrofit1 and rxjava1 and is just a pain to work with, so wrote a new one from scratch.

Every response to an API-request is enveloped with the following object

```
{
  "status":200,
  "payload": {}
}
```

I bypassed the envelope-problem by simply wrapping every response into a generic object and when accessing the payload, I can do that easily by calling the getter

```
class BaseResponse<T> {

  int status;
  T payload;

  public T getPayload(){
    return payload;
  }

}
```

The idea is to turn this `BaseResponse<T>` into `Observable<T>` and then call `map {it.payload}` to work with in some other place

```
interface API {

  @Body("blablabla")
  Observable<BaseResponse<SomeResponse>> someCall(@Body SomeRequest request);

}


public Observable<SomeResponse> someCall(SomeRequest request){

  return api.someCall(request)
    .map( response -> response.payload)

}
```

Now I've run into a problem. There are some API-requests, where the responsebody is defined as empty. I defined these empty responsebodies as `class EmptyResponse {}`

The problem is that I get those empty bodies like this

```
{
  "status":200,
  "payload":null
}
```

Now the problem is that `payload` is null and rxjava2 doesn't want null values.

---

Is there some way to have GSON deserialize `null` into an object of type `EmptyResponse`? Note that this ONLY occurs for calls that are documented to return empty responsebodies, there is no way that a call would return one, if it had a documented body

Comment: just check for null in the map() and return your EmptyResponse object

Comment: which is ugly and errorprone, because I need to remember to add that for calls that return EmptyResponse. in the end, I want to write an annotationprocessor over the retrofit interfaces that autogenerates all calls for me (because we have ~70 webcalls already in our app) and it would be simplest, if i didn't have to care about null values in the first place

Comment: well, as your `BaseResponse` is of some known T type, in your example let's say that T is `SomeResponse`, you have a method `getPayload` of type `SomeResponse`, GSON just can't turn this when there is null value to some other Object. so you need some post processing that extract this null value to some value.

Comment: as for the ugliness and error prone, I would argue differently, you can compose it and encapsulate this logic all over the place using retrofit call adapter or your annotation processing.